# Current OSs with multi-architecture support in the same installation?

Tags: multiarch

Apart from mach-o fat binaries in MacOS, are there any other (current) Unices that would allow to have the userland built for several architectures in the same installation, even if only one of such architectures can run natively on the user hardware?

I'm not asking if that's possible (everything is possible with hacks) but about OSs that have official support for multi architecture, with an established procedure where you could simply ask "please build the userland for x86_64 and ARMv8" (for example).

Comment: Is the "and" important in "please build the userland for x86_64 and ARMv8"? As in, are you looking for a single build targeting two architectures?

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessary that all architectures be packed in the same binary files (like mach-o does). A directory tree with a subtree for each architecture would be adequate too.

Comment: Would the i386/amd64 mixes on some linux systems to run steam, etc. count? of course, those are separate libraries, binaries, etc for each...

Comment: @ivanivan: That Linux 32/64 bit multi-arch binaries tree falls indeed within the behavior I was asking: several coexisting architectures, and the runtime linker chooses the appropriate architecture at runtime. However, I need more flexibility (i.e.: being able to have binaries from different CPUs). NOTE: My current decision is to choose Darwin, but I'd like to check if I have other options.